# iCloud UI Testing displays alert Sign In to iCloud, although logged in and iCloud is enabled for the app

Tags: xcode, icloud, xcode-ui-testing

My app uses iCloud, and I want to UI test it using simulators.
Thus, I logged in the simulators into iCloud using the system settings.
Now I can run my app without problems.

The problem arises when I try to UI test what happens when iCloud usage is disabled in the system settings app.

To do so, I launch first my app using

```
app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
```

Then, I want to disable iCloud usage in the settings app. Thus, I open this app using

```
let settingsApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")
settingsApp.launch()
```

This does indeed open the settings app, but for some reason, it displays an alert

[image]

I don’t why this alert is shown, because it happen only during UI testing, not when I run the app, hit the home button, and launch then settings app.

Moreover, I was not able to catch this alert using

```
let signInAlert = app.alerts["Sign In to iCloud"]
let signInAlertShown = signInAlert.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
```

`signInAlertShown` is set to `false` if I set a breakpoint after this statement in a UI test.

So my questions are:
1) Why is this alert shown?
2) How can I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I still don’t know why this alert is shown, but I know now how to handle it:

This alert is a system alert that appears asynchronously. Thus, it is **not** possible to access it with

```
app.alerts["Sign In to iCloud"].waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
```

Instead the app UI is interrupted. Thus the alert has to be catched by an alert monitor, and the test has to wait for it:

```
var alertMonitor: NSObjectProtocol!
var expectation: XCTestExpectation?
…
alertMonitor = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Alerts") { (alert) -> Bool in
  alert.collectionViews.secureTextFields["Password"].typeText("iCloud Password")
  expectation?.fulfill()
  alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
}
…
expectation = expectation(description: "signInToICloudAlert shown")
wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10.0)
```

Of course this is not the only asynchronous alert that can happen. Thus one has to check if the expected alert was shown. This has been omitted for clarity.